# Sending commands to dbx from Vim

Tags: vim, debugging

Using [this information](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_gvim_as_frontend_for_dbx), I've been able to debug code using `dbx` and display the code from within Vim.

What would be really cool is if I could send commands (step, next, print, stop in ... etc) to `dbx` from within Vim. I am relatively new to Unix so do not know of any way to do this.

Does anyone know how to send commands to `dbx` in this way? For example, sending commands to `dbx` from a separate process, or running `dbx` as a server?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute shell commands in vim using the command:  `:!foo -fooparam`

You can insert the output of shell commands similarly using: `:r!foo -fooparam`